# Issues with passing variables from form as Street View API parameters using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm just learning about javascript and working with the google street view api. i've been following a video on youtube to get a handle on the basics and i'm not sure why it's not working. here's all my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ajax and googleStreetView</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form-container" class="form-container">
        <!-- <label for="number">Number: </label><input type="text" id="number" value=""> -->
        <label for="street">Street: </label><input type="text" id="street" value="">
        <label for="city">City: </label><input type="text" id="city" value="">
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <br>
    <h2 id="address" class="address">Enter address</h2>
    <img class="photo" id="photo">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script:

```
function loadData() {
var $address = $('#address');
// var number = $('#number').val();
var street = $('#street').val();
var city = $('#city').val();

// var address = number + " " + street + ", " + city;
var address = street + ", " + city;
$address.text("Address: " + address + "");

var streetViewURL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x400&location=' + address + '';

$('#photo').attr("src", streetViewURL);

return false;
};

$('form-container').submit(loadData);
```

and the css:

```
body {
background-color: white;
}

.photo {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.address {
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

.form-container {
text-align: center;
}
```

i'm using Sublime Text 3 for the first time, probably that isn't helping my ability to understand. when i click Submit, nothing happens. One thing i'm concerned about: in the video i'm watching, the $ in the variable $address in the loadData function changes color. in my editor, the $ does not change color. as far as i understand sublimeText, i don't know whether this is just a visual bug in the program, or whether it is actually preventing my variable from being created. A few lines further on, the $address variable is used again, and in that case it is also not changing the color of the $ to indicate that it is a legal variable.

what am i doing wrong? thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: when i run the page with console open, there is no activity in the console. i'm using google chrome. thanks for your reply

Comment: `$('form-container').submit(loadData);` <-- simple typo... You are looking for an element, not an id

Answer (score 2):

You should add preventDefault() for submit event, just to stop default procedure  and your selector for `#form-container` element has typo:

```
function loadData(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $address = $('#address');
// var number = $('#number').val();
var street = $('#street').val();
var city = $('#city').val();

// var address = number + " " + street + ", " + city;
var address = street + ", " + city;
$address.text("Address: " + address + "");

var streetViewURL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x400&location=' + address + '';

$('#photo').attr("src", streetViewURL);

return false;
};

$('#form-container').submit(loadData);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and your help, i appreciate it

Comment: @grcHIDDEN, np,  it should work,  but still, let me know. cheers

Comment: hey @niklaz thank you it is working exactly as intended now i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`$('form-container').submit(loadData);`

To this:

```
$('#form-container').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    loadData();
});
```

Comment: thank you for your patience and time. appreciate it.

Comment: Cheers for the edit MadBreaks, haven't been here in a while couldn't remember how to format. I got it now though - backticks for inline code in comments